# htaccess redirect remove question mark from url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to remove question mark from the url and redirect to the same page without question mark.

My URL like:

```
http://domain.com/what-is-your-name?/21.php
```

URL needed:

```
http://domain.com/what-is-your-name/21.php
```

Answer (score 5):

This will remove any `?` mark from URL

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1%1? [R,L]
```

put it on as your first rule in .htaccess

**Short explanation:**

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$` checks is there any GET query string (like `?foobar` or `?foo=bar` or `?/21.php`) in url, it also fill up the `%1` variable.
When RewriteCond requirement if fullfiled, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` rewrites ANY url. `$1` is filled with URL part before `?` mark. `[R]` flag indicates it's a redirect. `[L]` means it's a last rule.

**I strongly recommend to not do this, and do it properly by fixing your links.**

**You can either escape question marks in URL's or remove it completely.**

Comment: I want to do this URL only. And also it is redirected url to the page as index.php?em=$1